# Scala: Companion objects for doubly F-Bounded Polymorphic types

Tags: scala, polymorphism, parametric-polymorphism

I have a F-Bound type:

```
sealed trait A[AA <: A[AA]] {
  self: AA =>
}
```

And a second F-Bound type, that is parametrized by the first type.

```
sealed trait B[BB <: B[BB, AA], AA <: A[AA]] {
  self: BB =>
  val content: AA
}
```

I can happily write case classes that makes use of these types:

```
case class BInst[BB <: BInst[BB, AA], AA <: A[AA]](content: AA) 
     extends B[BInst[BB, AA], AA]
```

Now I would like to have a companion object for the case class, which I can reference through the trait B, something like:

```
sealed trait A[AA <: A[AA]] { self: AA => }

sealed trait B[BB <: B[BB, AA], AA <: A[AA]] {
  self: BB =>
  val content: AA
  def companion: Companion[BB]
}

case class BInst[BB <: BInst[BB, AA], AA <: A[AA]](content: AA) 
     extends B[BInst[BB, AA], AA] {
  def companion: Companion[BInst[BB, AA]] = BInst
}

sealed trait Companion[+BB <: B[_, _]]
object BInst extends Companion[BInst]
```

But this fails to compile, as BInst in the companion parametrization (last line) requires type parameters.
Similarly

```
sealed trait Companion[BB[X, Y] <: B[X, Y]]
```

fails. What is the correct type for the companion object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I see is to abandon generic parameters for `Companion`/`BInst` as there might be only one instance of object even from type perspective (only one `BInst.type` type):

```
scala> sealed trait A[AA <: A[AA]] { self: AA => }

sealed trait B[BB <: B[BB, AA], AA <: A[AA]] {
  self: BB =>
  val content: AA
  def companion: Companion[_]
}

case class BInst[BB <: BInst[BB, AA], AA <: A[AA]](content: AA)
     extends B[BInst[BB, AA], AA] {
  def companion = BInst
}

sealed trait Companion[+BB <: B[_, _]]
object BInst extends Companion[BInst[_, _]]

defined trait A
defined trait B
defined class BInst
defined trait Companion
defined module BInst
```

After that you may actually cast your `BInst` (inside case class):

```
def companion: Companion[BInst[BB, AA]] = 
    BInst.asInstanceOf[Companion[BInst[BB, AA]]
```

If you don't cast types inside your `Companion`-trait/`BInst`-object (it's better to use only `BB`/`AA`-independent methods of `BInst` class) there is no risk to get ClassCastException, `.asInstanceOf[Companion[BInst[BB, AA]]]` will just create (clone) new type for you, using `BInst` as prototype.

Comment: What is the advantage of casting there?

Comment: In your original snippet you're asking for `def companion: Companion[BInst[BB, AA]]` - so if you're fine with `def companion: Companion[_]`, no advantage then :)

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to merge what you have written here with your other question:
[scala: Referencing Trait with F-Bound Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29750518/scala-referencing-trait-with-f-bound-parameters?noredirect=1#comment47726786_29750518)

This is as close as I could get to your code by keeping it compilable:

```
import scala.language.higherKinds

trait A[AA <: A[AA]] { self: AA => }

trait B[
  X <: A[X], 
  This[Y <: A[Y]] <: B[Y, This]
] {
  self: This[X] =>
  def content: X 
  def companion: Companion[This]
}

trait Companion[Coll[X <: A[X]] <: B[X, Coll]]

case class BInst[X <: A[X]](content: X) 
extends B[X, BInst] {
  def companion: Companion[BInst] = BInst
}

object BInst extends Companion[BInst]
```

Your `BB`s have been replaced by `This`, order of arguments has been swapped so that it is more similar to what is done in the standard collection library.

A general remark.
You don't seem to be quite sure about what you want from your `BInst` and `BComp`/`Companion`. It the two versions of your questions, they seem to have completely different types. If you are not quite sure what you want, it might be advisable to just keep it as simple as possible. There is anecdotal evidence that [all these F-Bound-GenericCompanionCanBuildFromFactories can be difficult to get right](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uiJycy6dFSQ).

Comment: Thanks! Parametrizing `B` with parametrized types is actually the solution, and not just to this problem! Thanks for the link to Paul's talk, he has a point.

Comment: Just in case that I've ruined your faith by providing the link to the talk: in the other version https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4jh94gowim0 all the other currently present languages are destroyed as well, and in general, the first version of this talk seems somewhat more optimistic (> 58:00). Furthermore, it's just an awesome entertaining performance, which should be considered art on its own.